# How to find Jar to which an Java class belongs

Tags: java

I need to know `TimedWindowEvent` class belongs to which JAR when JDK/JRE is downloaded. Is there any *generalized* way of searching Jar to which a particular class belongs to using Eclipse or any other tool. Right now, I have to open jar in WinRAR and go through each and every jar to find if class I am searching for is present there.

Comment: jar vtf jarFile.jar list content of a jar, depending on which OS you're running you can write a simple script doing this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468712/how-to-find-out-which-dependency-a-class-belongs-to

Comment: Include all possible jars to ur eclipse project dependencies. Then use the option Navigate->Open Type.... and type in the required classname to search for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could start by searching for the class on JarFinder.

http://www.findjar.com/

Not perfect as sometimes a class is in more than one JAR. But this may help narrow down the search.

If the link stops working, there are other similar services that can be found using you favourite search engine.

Answer (score 8):

In eclipse you could use `ctrl+shift+t` (That's means you are searching on targets ) it will popup a window and put your class name. It will show you jars that class name belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse, open some class and just import `TimedWindowEvent` class and press function key `F3` or press `Ctrl+mouse click` eclipse will take it to the jar the class comes from.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Eclipse, use the "Open Type" dialog (ctrl-shift-T) and search for the class.

When it is found, at the bottom of the dialog you can see which jar file it is in.

This only works if the jar file is in your classpath.

Comment: +1. Even thou a problem with this is when the Jar is not in eclipse runtime (e.g. is not used in any project's runtime)

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. This will open a dialog box. Enter the class name.
3. Then it will search all the matching class files
4. On selecting class file, at the bottom of the dialog box, it shows the jar file in the class path which contains this class.