# How do I know which jar files java program needs to run?

Tags: java, jar

Recently I was <del>[trying to run](https://github.com/aaronshaver/2048_bot/issues/1) [2048 bot](https://github.com/aaronshaver/2048_bot)</del> (**upd**: author deleted the project, but created [the new one](https://github.com/aaronshaver/2048_Bot_2.0)). But it just didn't work. And the developer said that it runs from `Intelij IDEA` just fine. And yes, it appeared it does. So what I did:

```
>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javac.exe" Program.java -cp selenium-java-2.41.0.jar
Note: Program.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

>java Program -cp selenium-java-2.41.0.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class Program
```

`Intelij IDEA` runs it this way:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\Desktop\2048_bot\2048_Bot_2.0-master\target\classes;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\2.39.0\selenium-firefox-driver-2.39.0.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\2.39.0\selenium-remote-driver-2.39.0.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.1_3\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\2.39.0\selenium-api-2.39.0.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\15.0\guava-15.0.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.1\httpclient-4.3.1.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3\httpcore-4.3.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.6\commons-codec-1.6.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.1\commons-exec-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.2\commons-io-2.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Program
```

Here are the `jar` files for convenience:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\charsets.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\deploy.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\javaws.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jce.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jfr.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\jsse.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\management-agent.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\plugin.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\resources.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\rt.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\Desktop\2048_bot\2048_Bot_2.0-master\target\classes
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\2.39.0\selenium-firefox-driver-2.39.0.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\2.39.0\selenium-remote-driver-2.39.0.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib-nodep\2.1_3\cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\2.39.0\selenium-api-2.39.0.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\15.0\guava-15.0.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.1\httpclient-4.3.1.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3\httpcore-4.3.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.6\commons-codec-1.6.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.1\commons-exec-1.1.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\3.4.0\jna-3.4.0.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\platform\3.4.0\platform-3.4.0.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.2\commons-io-2.2.jar
C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 13.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Program
```

So it starts with `jdk`'s `jar` files, then goes the project output directory, then some `jar` files, which are probably downloaded by `Intelij IDEA` on its own and it ends with the `Intelij IDEA`'s `jar` file, which is probably needed for debugging or something along those lines.

So, how do I know which `jar` files are needed and where do those `~/.m2` files come from?

**UPD** Here are probably the minimal `jar` files set to start this program:

```
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\2.39.0\selenium-firefox-driver-2.39.0.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\2.39.0\selenium-remote-driver-2.39.0.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20080701\json-20080701.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\2.39.0\selenium-api-2.39.0.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\15.0\guava-15.0.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.1\httpclient-4.3.1.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3\httpcore-4.3.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
C:\Users\Yuri\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.1\commons-exec-1.1.jar
```

So it's not all the `jar` files even in `m2` diretory.

**UPD** [Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/selenium-java-2.41.0.zip) comes with additional `jar` files but not all of them are needed. So one of the options was to specify all these `jar` files. But I was able to make it work this way:

```
>java Program
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver
        at Program.main(Program.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more

>java -cp "selenium-java-2.41.0.jar;." Program
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Function
        at Program.main(Program.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Function
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more

>java -cp "selenium-java-2.41.0.jar;guava-15.0.jar;." Program
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:87)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:77)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.<init>(FirefoxProfile.java:65)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.getProfile(FirefoxDriver.java:262)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:239)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
        at Program.main(Program.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 11 more

>java -cp "selenium-java-2.41.0.jar;guava-15.0.jar;json-20080701.jar;." Program
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/exec/Executor
        at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.<init>(CommandLine.java:47)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.startProfile(FirefoxBinary.java:96)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary.clean(FirefoxBinary.java:226)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:91)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
        at Program.main(Program.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.exec.Executor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 11 more

>java -cp "selenium-java-2.41.0.jar;guava-15.0.jar;json-20080701.jar;commons-exec-1.1.jar;." Program
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/params/HttpParams
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:93)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
        at Program.main(Program.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more

>java -cp "selenium-java-2.41.0.jar;guava-15.0.jar;json-20080701.jar;commons-exec-1.1.jar;httpclient-4.3.1.jar;." Program
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/params/HttpParams
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:93)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
        at Program.main(Program.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more

>java -cp "selenium-java-2.41.0.jar;guava-15.0.jar;json-20080701.jar;commons-exec-1.1.jar;httpcore-4.3.jar;." Program
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:93)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
        at Program.main(Program.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.auth.Credentials
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 8 more

>java -cp "selenium-java-2.41.0.jar;guava-15.0.jar;json-20080701.jar;commons-exec-1.1.jar;httpcore-4.3.jar;httpclient-4.3.1.jar;." Program
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.<init>(AbstractVerifier.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier.<init>(AllowAllHostnameVerifier.java:40)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLSocketFactory.java:145)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.getClientConnectionManager(HttpClientFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.HttpClientFactory.<init>(HttpClientFactory.java:48)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:100)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:81)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:93)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
        at Program.main(Program.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 15 more

>java -cp "selenium-java-2.41.0.jar;guava-15.0.jar;json-20080701.jar;commons-exec-1.1.jar;httpcore-4.3.jar;httpclient-4.3.1.jar;commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;." Program
```

**UPD** Alternatively:

```
find -name '*.jar' -execdir cp -t ~/path/to/prj {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

If you compile

```
javac Program.java
```

then `Program.class` will be generated. This must be in your classpath.

```
java -cp "Program.class;selenium-java-2.41.0.jar"
```

Comment: That made me realize I should add `.` or `Program.class` if I specify `-cp` option.

Answer (score 1):

A Java program does not need any specific jar files to run, but it need the contained classes.
There are various tools and sites to help you find out:

- [How to find Jar to which an Java class belongs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951175/how-to-find-jar-to-which-an-java-class-belongs)

There are also tools to help you manage those dependencies, like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) (.m2 is related to it).
The author states that

> You will need to install the Selenium dependency somehow, such as by using Maven.

IMHO the project should come with a pom.xml or the jars.

Comment: `jarfinder.com` doesn't work and the question is how do I run `java` program without installing an `IDE`. [Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/selenium-java-2.41.0.zip) comes with additional `jar` files but not all of them are needed. Probably I could just specify them all for it to work. Also, the author created [another repository](https://github.com/aaronshaver/2048_Bot_2.0) with blackjack and `pom.xml`. Is there a way I could use this `pom.xml` thing without installing an `IDE`?

Comment: Yes but you must install Maven, once installed you can run it via command line (mvn clean install), in the folder where the pom is located. See Maven install and setup. Maven will download the jars for you and place them in a .m2 folder on your machine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on using `maven`? It [created](http://sprunge.us/NBPi) `target\AutoVisit2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`, and some files in `~/.m2` directory, but I don't know how to make it run.

Comment: @x-yuri The Maven site has documentation and tutorials that will guide you through the process better than I will.