# How do I compile and run Intelij IDEA java project without IDE?

Tags: java, maven, compilation

Recently I was trying to run [2048 bot](https://github.com/aaronshaver/2048_Bot_2.0). I'm not a `java` programmer and installing `IDE` just for running one program would be overkill. So I tried compiling and running it from command line, but that was not a simple task for me, mainly because of [the dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810359/how-do-i-know-which-jar-files-java-program-needs-to-run). Then I was told, that `maven` might come in handy. So I wonder if one can easily compile and run a program using `maven` or whatever tool they have without installing `IDE`?

Comment: Check out my post, it has all the instructions you need, Thanks!
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830611/2048-game-bot-hack-free?r=SearchResults&s=2|78.0366>

Answer (score 4):

The `pom.xml` file will have everything in it you need to compile it. In this particular case, it is only declaring a single dependency, the `selenium-firefox-driver`. With maven, all POM (Project Object Model) files inherit defaults from a "master" parent POM file. Maven uses a "convention over configuration" philosophy. Anything not explicitly configured, defaults to standard configurations from the parent pom that is part of maven. That is why you can build a project from such a seemingly simple POM file.

You will not be able to run the build from the IntelliJ IDEA module (`.iml`) file. In fact, IntelliJ IDEA generates that file from the POM.

First, make sure you have a [Java JDK installed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). Java 8 is the latest current. But a Java 7 JDK would be fine. After that, the [Running Maven](http://maven.apache.org/run-maven/index.html) link @jeroen_de_schutter provided has all the information you need. Click on the top link in that document to [Download and Install Maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.html). Once that is done, from a command line, navigate into the directory that contains the project (i.e. the directory with the `pom.xml` file in it) and issue the command: `mvn compile` to compile your code, `mvn test` to compile and test, or `mvn package` to compile, test and package the code. You can add `clean` to that any of those commands so maven will do a clean build. For example: `mvn clean package`. See the second [Quick Start](http://maven.apache.org/run-maven/index.html#Quick_Start) and third [Use Maven](http://maven.apache.org/users/index.html) links in the *Running Maven* document for more details and information.

Please note that the first time you run a build (any maven build) it will take quite a bit longer than normal. This is because maven has to download (and cache) a ton of plug-ins and dependencies. Once that is done, the builds go much much quicker. However, the first time you build a new project, the first build make take a little longer as it downloads and caches the dependencies and plug-ins needed by that project that have not already been retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Things are getting clearer. I might haven't made myself clear enough though. I was able to compile the program, because I knew there were that `selenium` dependency. So I just downloaded the first thing on their download page that were labeled with a word `java`. Then `javac Program.java -cp selenium-java...jar` and it's there, waiting for me to run it. But then the real problems started. Suddenly, `selenium-java...jar` wasn't enough anymore to run the program. In the end, I run the program, but that was way too hard.

Comment: And now I realize, that `maven` has nothing to do with the second part, running the program that is. So I see the following ways to run the program: 1) run the program, see which classes are needed, download and add corresponding `jar`-file, and so on until it just runs (see last shell transcript in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22810359/how-do-i-know-which-jar-files-java-program-needs-to-run)), 2) take a look at `iml`-file, they all are supposedly there. The second way seems easier, if `iml`-file exists that is. Are there any better ways to run the program?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, make sure you have a Java Development Kit and Maven installed. Then by following the [Maven user guides](http://maven.apache.org/run-maven/index.html) you should be able to build it and run.
But it might not be straightforward if you have never used maven, so I would recommend to ask the assitance of an experienced java developer, if you happen to know one.

Comment: So here I am, asking an experienced java developer ;) As far as I can tell, [pom.xml](https://github.com/aaronshaver/2048_Bot_2.0/blob/master/pom.xml) doesn't contain enough information. [2048_Bot.iml](https://github.com/aaronshaver/2048_Bot_2.0/blob/master/2048_Bot.iml) seems more like it, but it's `IDEA`'s file which `maven` wouldn't read, I take it. By inspecting `2048_Bot.iml` I can run it manually, downloading and specifying all the dependencies. But I wonder if `maven` can simplify the task.

Comment: The pom should have everything you need. The iml file is for intellij's consumption, not for humans -- it contains things IntelliJ needs, not things that you need. The pom is everything, trust in it.